# Wrong total of a measure Power BI in a table

Tags: filter, sum, powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables with data: Rapport 1 and Engagement_TagData.

I have the following values: **Chargeable Hours**, **DnA Team Hours** ( a measure) in Rapport 1 and **inclus** ( a measure) in Engagement_TagData that has the values 0 or 1.
I created a measure **HeuresFinales** that goes like: if **inclus** is **1** it'll take the value in **Chargeable Hours**, if it is **0**, it'll take the value in **DnA Team Hours**, but the total value for **HeuresFinales** is wrong, it gives me the same total as for Chargeable Hours.

[image]

The total value for HeuresFinales should be less than the total for Chargeable Hours.

Can someone help me find the right DAX function the get the right total for HeuresFinales.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are assuming inclus(measure) will evaluate to 1 or 0 for each row in that table and apply the aggregation correctly. That is not how it works. Could you include the actual measures DAX formulas?

Comment: the measure DAX formula for Heuresfinales is: 
HeuresFinales = SUM('Rapport 1'[Chargeable Hours])*Max(Engagements_TagData_Reviewed[inclus]) + 'Rapport 1'[DnA Team Hours]*(1-MAX(Engagements_TagData_Reviewed[inclus]))

Comment: 72518,5*1+11984,5*(1-1) = 72518,5 -> rounded to 0 decimal cases 72519 I see no problem here.

Comment: the last row is supposed to be the total of the column HeuresFinales, but as you pointed it just calculates 72518,5*1+11984,5*(1-1) = 72518,5, but I don't want that because when I create a visualization ( a pie chart for example) and I want to display HeuresFinales per fields of play it gives me that values of Chargeable hours and no Heuresfinales. I don't know if what I'm saying is clear!

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing your DAX function in a SUMX iterator over the Report 1 table to force row level calculation also when computing a total value.

```
    SUMX (
        'Rapport 1' ;
        IF ( 
            Max(Engagements_TagData_Reviewed[inclus]) = 1 ;
            'Rapport 1'[Chargeable Hours] ;
            'Rapport 1'[DnA Team Hours]
        )
    )
```

Comment: Nice idea, but sadly it doesn't work, it gives me a circular dependency error!

Comment: Can you give me more information on the error? I assume it refers to the `Max(Engagement_tagData_Reviewd[inclus])`? Do you have the DAX of this measure?